# python delay without blocking after condtion met with high precision

Tags: python, delay, python-multithreading, blocking

I need to execute a function in python after condition is met, but before executing the function there are a slight second delay without blocking another program in the loop, and the delay must be high precision.

Is there any way to do that? i've tried using `threading.Thread` and `threading.Timer` but the delay is not that precise. Here is my code:

```
count = 2500
delay = 0.5 # delay before executing function
while True:
    # Another program here
    .......
    if(count <= 2000):
        if(found == 0): # Run once until count >= 2000 again
            # Execute pressKey function
            startThread = threading.Timer(delay, pressKey).start()
        found = 1

    if(count >= 2000):
        if(found == 1): # Run once until count <= 2000 again
            # Execute releaseKey function
            endThread = threading.Timer(delay, releaseKey).start()
        found = 0
```

Assume that the variable `count` is decreasing until 0 and increasing until 2500 sequencially, and the `if condition` is not just that two i mentioned, there are 6 more `if condition` similiar to the code above with different `count` variable.

Comment: **You can run only one process at the same time.**
The shared object should be stored in the global variable in the flag and values. The first stage in creating stability or speed the process, you have to choose. A section in each status flag processor time must pass the scan. Lath applications sync is hard. nothing must be written application without writing the prototype. According to the values of the actual implementation of the prototype are restricted to transactions. This is a complicated situation, depends on your system and hardware speed/competence.

Comment: @dsgdfg I'm sorry, i'm a bit hard understanding your comments about flag, processor, lath applications sync, but which process do you mean that can run only one at the same time? it is the `threading.Timer`?

Comment: Global flags are used in the child processes that have a data relationship. For example Run_sub_thread (my_global_var_1,...), Run_sub_thread1 (my_global_var_1,...), you cannot change the my_global_var_1 variable (in the sub-process). Administrator, Practitioner, controller, security are indispensable parts of an application. **You can perform one operation at a time on the computer (for the programmer).** You can initiate different processes, but it actually means running a single transaction, since the filter will advance to a specific step. **Chronos has all the controls.**